# Template inheritance in C++ and undefined symbols on Xcode

Tags: templates, inheritance

I have seen many related questions to this problem, but after carefully following advice from members, my problem still persists. The code is quite simple. I only have the following header file ("instrument.h"), which contains the base class and the template class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Instrument
{
public:
    Instrument();
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

template <class parameter> class Equity : public Instrument
{
public:
    Equity();
    virtual void print() const;
};
```

Now, in my main function on main.cpp I only do the following:

```
#include "instrument.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    Equity<double> pb;        
    return 0;
}
```

Well, I get the very well-known error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Equity<double>::Equity()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already changed in Build Settings the C++ standard library to libstdc++, also to default compiler, and so on. Do I have a problem with my project settings? Is perhaps the template wrongly implemented? I was thinking I should also have a instrument.cpp file, but then again definitions for templates must be kept in the header file so that would probably crash too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the default constructors for both `Instrument` and `Equity` but defined them nowhere.

Alter their definitions appropriately:

```
public:
    Equity() = default; // Or {} in pre-C++11
//           ^^^^^^^^^
```

(And equivalently for `Instrument`)

You can also completely omit the declarations of any default constructors for now since you didn't declare any other constructors in both `Equity` and `Instrument` and the default constructors will be generated automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately none of those options work, keep getting the same error.

Comment: changed both accordingly, tried even several combinations, still same error.

Comment: @Adam ... that sounds quite impossible. Have you saved the header after the changes? Have you also implemented the derived `print` function (e.g. `{}`), just to be sure?
You mean to tell me that [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bdfa5379335fb83) doesn't compile on your machine?

Comment: it does actually, but I had to replace the "default" by "{}", and also add the {} after the "print" declaration in the Equity class, like what you've done. Cheers for that.